# How can i know the root div when clicked on a element

Tags: jquery

I have got section element with  class "secclass" in two div's

```
<div id="69" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
   <div class="prd-items-detials">
   </div>
   <div style="" class="Topping-details" id="69">
      <section id="topping_tsection_69">
         <aside>
            <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>
            <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" topping_id="17" id="69_ZZ_0_ZZ_0" topp_name="Honey with Carmel  10 ML" top_cost="30" class="tpActive" qt_val="69_ZZ_0_ZZ_0">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
         </aside>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

And also under this

```
<div id="addtoordersdiv69">
   <div class="prd-items-detials">
   </div>
   <div style="" class="Topping-details" id="69">
      <section id="topping_tsection_69">
         <aside>
            <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>
            <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" topping_id="17" id="69_ZZ_0_ZZ_0" topp_name="Honey with Carmel  10 ML" top_cost="30" class="tpActive" qt_val="69_ZZ_0_ZZ_0">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
         </aside>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have got a listener registered for the section element with its class secclass

My question is when clicked on the section element how can i know if it belongs to the first div or second div ??

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function(e) {



});
```

I have tried it this way

```
 $(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function(e) {

if($(this).hasClass("activateUiHTML"))
{
    alert('from activehtmlui');
}

else
{
alert('from myorders'); 
}
    });
```

But it isn't working .

Comment: You are using `id="topping_tsection_69"` multiple times, use class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `length` of parent div with `class="activateUiHTML"` like below

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function(e) {

  if($(this).closest(".activateUiHTML").length > 0)
  {
    alert('from activehtmlui');
  }
  else
  {
    alert('from myorders'); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function(e) {
  var $divPar = $(this).parents("div");
  alert($divPar.attr("id"));
  });
```

by analysing $divPa you could find the result as you desire

Comment: Hi Sarath with this i  get the same value from both the div's . can i work out this way $(this).hasClass("activateUiHTML")??

Comment: then put a specifisc class (like mainDiv) on both divs. And rewrite the code as

$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function(e) {
  var $divPar = $(this).parents("div.mainDiv");
  if($(this).hasClass("activateUiHTML")) alert("1st div");
  });


Hope this will work for you now. Sorry for the careless typings. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sth like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function(e) {

    console.log($(this).closest('.Topping-details').parent('div').index());

});
```

but i would use a class to those divs like `.module` and then use jQuery like:

```
$(this).closest('.module').index();
```

Test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UFDBv/) on jsfiddle.

Also be careful because you use twice `id="69"` and `id="topping_tsection_69"` in your code and `id` should be unique. Prefer data attributes like `data-id="69"` or `data-id="topping_tsection_69"`.

Comment: For the First div i get [div#69.activateUiHTML, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: a#69_ZZ_0_ZZ_0, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…] , can i extract activateUiHTML from this ??

Comment: Do you still want the index of the parent divs? Now you have it. Did you check your console? My code returns their index like 0 or 1 accordingly.